# If I ride a bike/If I rode a bike

Tags: grammar, modal-verbs

This relates to 'if' clauses, let's say you were asked a hypothetical question, which was riding a bike to work.

> "my house is 20 kilometers away from my work, and I will be late, **if I ride a bike to work.”**

Or

> "my house is 20 kilometers away from my work, and I will be late, **if I rode a bike to work.”**

Which is correct?

Comment: The first sentence is correct. Is sounds like you are sure that you will be late in case go by bike. Anyway, you would say "I would be late if I rode...".

Comment: The first sentence is **not** correct.  Both commas do not belong. The first is a comma splice and the second orphans a conditional clause.  It is best to make these two separate sentences: "My house is 20km away from my workplace.  I will be late if I ride a bike to work."  Also acceptable:  "My house is 20km away from my workplace; so, I will be late if I ride a bike."  The second example in the OP also suffers from these issues.

Answer (score 2):

Here are more details:
https://www.ef.edu/english-resources/english-grammar/conditional/

> "I will be late, if I ride a bike to work."

This is the type 1 conditional. It is a correct way to express the sentence, and indicates that it's possible and also very likely the condition will be fulfilled, meaning that you have a bike and contemplate riding it to work.

> "I will be late, if I rode a bike to work."

Not correct. The main clause is in the future and the conditional is in the past. Fix the problems by changing "will" to "would":

> "I would be late, if I rode a bike to work."

This is the type 2 conditional. It is a correct way to express the sentence, and indicates that it's possible but very unlikely the condition will be fulfilled, meaning that you don't really plan on riding a bike to work.

Therefore, with adjustments, both choices could be correct, although they have different meanings.

Comment: So what is the answer to the question?  :-)